# C for condition tricks

Tags: c, for-loop

I found a challenge on the internet and I'm really stuck.
The goal is to print 20 times `_` by adding/changing only **1** character (only one operation performed in total):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int n=20;
    for(i=0;i<n;i--)
    {
        printf("_");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have already found 1 solution but I can't find the last one? Is there some tricks I need to know about for loops ?

Comment: Please post the other two, to avoid answers with the same ones.

Comment: you change i-- in n-- and i-- and --n

Comment: Plesae add this to the question.

Comment: Is it really one character or one token?

Comment: @LouisAspas How does `i--` to `--n` count as changing only 1 character? It would seem you are removing one and adding another.

Comment: @Acorn oh yes you are right :/

Comment: You can think of that loop as `i` being the negation of what it normally is, so..

Comment: @Gerhardh 3 ways to fix the program

Comment: @harold I don't understand why `i&(i-1)` is not counted as a single move where `i` is initially `2^20 -1`

Comment: @harold thank you found another one thanks to you :)
So i-- to n-- and -i < n works perfectly

Comment: @Observer that's a good trick, but it takes more than 1 character

Comment: To clarify the rules: Does the limit of 1 char apply to each of the operations? Or are you allowed to touch one character in total?

Comment: @harold Can you please explain?

Comment: @Gerhardh one character in total, would be too easy I think

Comment: @Gerhardh already found 2 ;)

Comment: I can see 1. Changing `i--` to `--n` touches 2 characters.

Comment: @Gerhardh I know I replace it now its -i < n my second solution

Comment: You would have received those solutions earlier if you had phrased the quix as in the posted web page: "change/add only one character" not " *removing* /adding/changing ..." ;)

Comment: regarding: `for(i=0;i<n;i--)`  where `n` is initialized to 20.  This will cause the loop to execute some (in a 32 bit architecture) some 2 (or 4) gig iterations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `i` by `n`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int i, n = 20; 
    for (i = 0; i < n; n--) 
        printf("*"); 
    getchar();     
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Put `-` before `i`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int i, n = 20; 
    for (i = 0; -i < n; i--) 
        printf("*");            
    getchar();     
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Replace `<` by `+`

```
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
    int i, n = 20; 
    for (i = 0; i + n; i--) 
       printf("*"); 
    getchar(); 
    return 0; 
}
```

---

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/changeadd-only-one-character-and-print-exactly-20-times/

Comment: these possibilities are changing a LOT more than just one char.  The major change is placing the declarations of the  variables into the same statement. (always a bad idea)

Answer (score 0):

to correct the posted code to only output 20 times, you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    int n=-20;   // note the minus 20
    for(i=0;i<n;i--)
    {
        printf("_");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If it is allowed you could write:

```
n=10; for(i=0;i<n;i++){printf("__");}
```

or

```
n=10; for(i=0;i<n;i++){printf("_");printf("_");}
```

Comment: the requirement is *removing/adding/changing only 1 character*